# EWS - combine query string with search filter object

Tags: exchangewebservices

The Exchange Web Services `FindItems()` call has some overloads taking a `SearchFilter` object and others taking a query string in Advanced Query Syntax (AQS).  Currently I accept AQS queries, such as "subject:Foo OR subject:Bar", from callers to my code and pass them on to EWS.

But now I would like to do some filtering using a `SearchFilter` too, to restrict by date range.  Although it is possible to do that in AQS syntax as "date:>11/05/04", I feel it is cleaner to specify the filter programmatically:

```
new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, d);
```

So what I'd like to do is query by *both* a `SearchFilter` and a query string.  To do that I would like to convert the query string I've received into a `SearchFilter` object so I can then 'and' it together with my own filtering.

Is there a way to construct a `SearchFilter` on the client given an AQS query string?

Answer (score 3):

Partially answering my own question: I suspect this is not possible because EWS does not support query strings on public folders, but it does support `SearchFilter` objects on public folders.  Therefore, a `SearchFilter` cannot offer the functionality of query strings, unless this EWS restriction is just pointless.

Comment: You're probably right. Sterling's "Inside Microsoft® Exchange Server 2007 Web Services" only mentions search filters, not AQS